# How The Spring Security is redirecting to Login page if User is unauthorized

Tags: spring-security

- What is the Internal mechanism of authorization by spring-security?
- How it is redirecting the URL to `/Login` if a user does not enters valid credentials?
- Who is responsible for this Action?
- What is the internal flow of project ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All the important magic is in the [security filter chain](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html).

At some point some component checks whether the request is authenticated. Usually it is the last filter - [`FilterSecurityInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/intercept/FilterSecurityInterceptor.html) (checking access conditions based on request path), but it can be  `MethodSecurityInterceptor` (`@Secured` annotation check) or even your own custom code. The important thing is that this check will end in `AuthenticationException` or `AccessDeniedException` being thrown.

The next important component is [`ExceptionTranslationFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/ExceptionTranslationFilter.html). This filter checks if the thrown exception is `AuthenticationException` or `AccessDeniedException` and calls configured `AuthenticationEntryPoint`. Depending on the configured authentication mechanism, this might send redirect to login page or 401 response with `WWW-Authenticate` header (e.g. BASIC auth).

---

So the overall process for FORM based login looks like this (it might look like a mess, but it is actually pretty well designed and not that complex once you understand the principles):

- unauthenticated user makes request to `/foo.html`

  - request is checked by `FilterSecurityInterceptor` against your security expression `isAuthenticated()` and throws `AccessDeniedException`
  - thrown exception is catched by `ExceptionTranslationFilter`, which in turn calls `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint`
  - entry point sends `301` redirect response to `/login.html`
- user makes another request to `/login.html`

  - request is checked by `FilterSecurityInterceptor` and for this path, anonymous access is allowed
  - login form is presented to user
- user fills the login form and submits it as `POST /login.html`

  - this request is intercepted by authentication processing filter `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`
  - username and password is extracted and `AuthenticationManager` is called to perform actual authentication (actual authentication is delegated to other components - usually `DaoAuthenticationProvider` and `UserDetailsService`)
  - authentication is successful and the `Authentication` token is marked as `authenticated` and put on `SecurityContextHolder` (so it is available to other components)
  - `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` is being called, which might just redirect user back to `/foo.html`
  - on the way up, the successful authentication is being picked up by `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` (checks `SecurityContextHolder`), which stores authentication on the HTTP session
- user makes yet another request to `/foo.html`

  - `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` restores authentication from session onto `SecurityContextHolder`
  - `FilterSecurityInterceptor` checks your access rule again and allows further processing for the freshly authenticated request (i.e. dispatcher servlet is called)
  - user enjoys his `/foo.html`

Comment: Thanks  @pavel this made clear some internal mechanism.

Comment: I don't have sufficient reputations.

Comment: In what case does the AuthenticationException being thrown ?

Comment: Just check the various descendants of the [AuthenticationException](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/AuthenticationException.html) and their JavaDoc.